# How to replace EraseMode in Matlab 2014b

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am using a function in which the `EraseMode` property is used as follows:

```
line('Color',[1 1 1],'EraseMode','background',  ...
     'Xdata', x(i)+[0 0], 'Ydata',[zstart zend]);
```

Now that I am using Matlab2014b, this property is no longer used and I get a warning each time I run the code.

How can I replace this function in the above code?

Comment: It's [in the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/graphics_transition/how-do-i-replace-the-erasemode-property.html?)...

Comment: It is stated that it can be replaced by animatedline, but I don't know how to replace it in the line of code I mentioned here